# CustomScrollbar too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I am working with the [customscrollbar plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to create a cross browser custom scrollbar.

The issue is, I can't figure out why my scrollbar is too sensitive. On a touchpad, it goes down by almost 400 px with a slight scroll. Same for the mousewheel as well.
I tried debugging in and I thought that the issue might be because of the mousewheel plugin, but still no luck.

My code is pretty straight forward -

```
$('body').mCustomScrollbar({ scrollInertia:1500 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with mousewheel events - touchpad generates several times more `mousewheel` events than usual mouse. New version of plugin (3.0.2) incorrectly handles mousewheel events generated by touchpad. Try previous version (2.8.3) - it handles touchpad mousewheel correctly (as I can see from my examples) or contact author and create the bug in issue tracker.

Comment: Yeah.. that fixed it. A few other plugins are facing the same issue I guess. Tried patching the new version but didn't work that well. Reverting to the previous version seems like the only option.

Comment: You can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) if you want cross browser CSS customizable scrollbar. Maybe it will fit your needs, maybe not.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks.. will look into it. While I am at it, is there any possible way to create a custom scrollbar without disrupting the HTML? I have an iframe which has user generated content and creating a custom scrollbar screws up the css which is linked to the container and child elements

Comment: if you use scrollbar that emulates scrolling by handling mousewheel/touch, then HTML remains the same (+adds HTML for scrollbar into your container usually). If you prefer scrollbar plugin that uses native scrolling, then you need changes in HTML, at least wrap your content into another div. Can you make an example on jsFiddle.net where custom scrollbar screws up the css?

Comment: Yeah sure, will make a fiddle.. I tried emulating the scrollbar using jQuery Sliders and linking it to mousewheel and scroll events.. but it needed a lot more handling (like updating the height/width automatically when adding more content) etc. so I scrapped it .. seemed too much work

Comment: @KshitizShankar it looks like simple thing to do, but it is a lot of work, believe me, I did custom scrollbar, and it's still not finished after 1.5 year of development :). Of course basic functinality is simple and can be done in few hours, but the rest... also, handling mousewheel events is not good idea - many native things won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define where to actually scroll, for example:

```
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom",
        { scrollInertia:1500 });
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong - I am not looking to programmatically change the scroll position. After the scrollbars are created, my issue is that they are too sensitive for the touchpad/mouseheel.

"Call the scrollTo method to programmatically scroll the content"